# TAB completion what it returns

Tags: canopy

my apologies for being stupid, but I am new to Canopy.
What does completion return?
when I type 
print(), I get a list of %%??? items.
I am looking for info about the print() function or other functions.
I am sure it's in that manual but I can't find it.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Tab completion tries to show you a list of everything that might complete what you are typing.

`print` is unusual because it is both a python 2.7 keyword and a python-3-compatible function. IPython doesn't know what you want to print so it shows you the beginning of a list of every name it knows.

In contrast, if you type `plot?` you will see good help for matplotlib's plot function, etc.